# block specific udp packet with iptables

Tags: networking, udp, iptables, rtp

```
Is it possible to block specific udp packet using iptables?
```

[image]

**for example I want to block packet containing** `bd 65` **like at line 3, that is a sequence number of RTP packet**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the iptables "u32" module will allow you to take action on bit/byte values at a given offset (even with variable-length headers).  The syntax is extremely ugly, but it will get the job done.  Search for "iptables u32" and you'll find details & examples.

The line would look something like this:

```
... -m u32 --u32 "44&0xFFFF=0xBD65" -j DROP
```

(grab a 4-byte chunk starting at offset 44, AND with 0xFFFF, compare with 0xBD65)

Answer (score -1):

Iptables is not able to block packet based on its payload[1].

You need Deep Packet inspection(DPI) in order to filter such a packet.

I've never use it but it seems that http://l7-filter.clearfoundation.com/ could help you.

Notice : DPI may slow down your throughput. and moreover, there are a lot of legal restriction in some area....

[1]: You may ask iptables to block packet matching a string (try : iptables -m string --help )